# The type or namespace 'code' could not be found

Tags: mvc

In my Helix based solution, every time I publish a change to a feature project  and load the site I get this error below.

The error goes away when I publish the website project in the project layer. So every time I publish a feature project in my development box I'm having to republish the website project as well.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this? I can't find "using code" anywhere in my solution.

[image]

Comment: Right click > Find Reference. You tell us where it is.

Comment: What do you mean; "where is it defined?"   It's defined right there. It's your code.

Comment: There is no reference to "using code" anywhere in my solution. Seems to be something that ASP.Net generates when it is compiling my default layout View file? I can only see it in the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder

Comment: OK, I think Visual Studio is holding on to a reference somewhere.Since I create all my projects calling it "code" to create the code folder following Helix conventions and then rename it to the actual project. But as far as I can tell I changed all references to "code" and as mentioned it works when I just recompile the project again. Very Odd

Comment: No, it definitely isn't Visual Studio holding a reference. I'm pretty sure it's because you trigger a recompilation of the views when you publish the feature - these are by default not precompiled.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the issue. I was looking for "using code" in my solution and wondering where that reference came from, but what I should have been looking for is

```
<add namespace="code" />
```

I found this in the Views folder web.config of all of my Feature projects. Since I was creating all my projects using the name "code" to follow the Helix module structure and then renaming them to the actual name I want, Visual Studio was adding that as a default namespace in the Views web.config folder.

```
/…
    /[Module Name]
        /code
            /Views/web.config
```

Hope someone finds this useful.